# Why does this code not compile in CUDA c++20 standard?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

This code should compile but it doesn't and I don't know why: https://godbolt.org/z/c8ox9KoGY

I get this error:

```
    <source>:1:20: error: expected identifier before '>' token
        1 | template <typename T>
          |                    ^
```

foo doesn't compile while bar and baz do compile. I don't know if this is a bug.

**foo on gcc does compile.**

```
    template <typename T> 
    void foo(T& arg0, auto arg1)
    {
        auto func = []<typename S>(S arg){};
    }
    
    template <typename T> 
    void bar(T& arg0)
    {
        auto func = []<typename S>(S arg){};
    }
    
    template <typename T> 
    void baz(T& arg0, auto arg1)
    {
    }
```

Comment: If you also add `-x=c++` to the nvcc arguments, it compiles. I guess it can't always correctly detect the file type in godbolt?

Comment: @skandigraun When you use godbolt in CUDA mode why would the file type be `.cpp`? Also I don't think that this really solves the issue as CUDA makes a point out of being able to have host and device code in the same source file. `-x=c++` just calls the host compiler on the file where we already know that it will work.

Comment: Looks like a `nvcc` bug to me. Ideally this should also be tested against CUDA 12.3 which isn't on godbolt yet.